# SQL not sending data from php script to DB

Tags: php, sql

```
$timeforlog = date("H:i:s");
$dateforlog = date("d/m/y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = $dateforlog;
$time = $timeforlog;
$link = $actual_link;
$responsefromsite = $response;
$response = trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $output));
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO logs (ondate, ontime, link, ip, response) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $date, $time, $link, $ip,$responsefromsite);
$stmt->execute();
```

Its expected to go ahead and add to the database. However despite tables being correct as shown below, it wont.

(note: the `?` and `t` lines shown in the table was testing the queries)
[image: Table contents]

Comment: note stuff shown in db was testing the queries

Comment: Have you got error reporting switched on? [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman i turned that on still no output

Comment: Please update the question with the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE logs`

Comment: Are you sure this code is even executed?

Comment: Yes i am sure it has executed

Comment: Is there more related code before the one you've shown? It's a bit weird, you use the `$response` variable: `$responsefromsite = $response;` before it's defined on the next line.

Comment: just noticed and fixed that thanks @El_Vanja but still not sending to DB

Comment: Do a check: echo out all the values you wish to insert. Also check that the table column names are correct in your code.

Comment: collums are correct as i tested going through and manually adding each as `t` which is shown in image attached I will now try to echo each variable

Comment: @SJacks there is one variable it cannot echo being link which is the following however despite trying to hardcode to the word test still wont send to db ```$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";```

Comment: @crazychris This looks like the problem. All variables must be able to be echoed if they are to be inserted or the insert will fail. Set that link to any static value and retry the insert, it should work. Other than that, check that the column for the link on your table is set to a type of text.

Comment: @SJacks still no luck having all as set variables however when changing direct query without variables it sends